# AngularJS using UI-JQ with Two-Way Data Binding

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Good Evening,

I have a small issue when I am trying to create a wizard form using jQuery Steps inside AngularJS. I can pass data into the plugin, but I cannot get the plugin to send data back to my controller. Here is how I have it setup:

**jqConfig**

```
myApp.value('uiJqConfig', {
    steps: {}
};
```

**Conroller**

```
myApp.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.user = {
        name = "",
        address = ""
    };

    $scope.wizardOptions = {
        onStepChanging: function (event, currentIndex, newIndex) {
            console.log($scope.user);
        }
    };
```

**HTML Template**

```
<form ui-jq="steps" ui-options="wizardOptions">
    <h1>Step 1</h1>
    <div>
        <input ng-model="user.name" />
    </div>
    <h1>Step 2</h1>
    <div>
        <input ng-model="user.address" />
    </div>
</form>
```

I get the wizard to load up properly and everything. Now the issue is when I type into the inputs, it does not update the user object inside the controller.

Is there a way that I can accomplish this at all? Or should I look for a different solution?

Thanks,
Joshua